# Right div pushing center div further down

Tags: css

I cannot get this last div to go up properly in my layout and have tried countless things. I'm not sure what's going on with my css?
Here is a screenshot: http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/5377/screenshot20100528at123.png

```
 #events {
     float: left;
     width: 420px;
     margin:0 0 5px 0;
     font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
     font-size: 16px;
     background-image: url(images/lastfmhead.jpg);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     height:360px;
     overflow:hidden;
     display: inline;
    }
    #events table {
     width:419px;
    }
    #events th, td {
     padding: 3px 3px;

    }
    #whatsup ul, #citywhatsup ul  {
     margin:0 5px 0 5px;
     text-align:left;
     font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    #whatsup ul li, #citywhatsup ul li{
     list-style-type:none;
     list-style: none;
    }
    #whatsup hr, #citywhatsup hr{
     border: none 0;
     border-top: 1px dashed #990000;/*the border*/
     width: 100%;
     height: 1px;
     margin: 1px auto 5px auto;/*whatever the total width of the border-top and border-bottom equal*/
    }

    #events ul {
     margin:5px 5px 0 5px;

    }
    #events ul li{
     list-style-type:none;
     list-style: none;
    }
    #attending ul {
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 0;
     width:200px;
    }
    #attending ul li {
     display: inline-block;
     list-style-image:none;
     margin:0;
     padding:2px 5px 2px 5px;
    }

    #attending {
     width: 230px;
     margin:0 13px 5px 12px;
     float: left;
     display: inline;
     background-image: url(images/otherhead.jpg);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     text-align:center;
     height:360px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    #whatsup {
     width: 230px;
     margin:0 0 5px 0;
     float: left;
     display:inline;
     background-image: url(images/otherhead.jpg);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     text-align:center;
    }
    #eventtitle{
     margin: 3px 0 -3px 0;
    }

    #eventtitle {
     color: #900;
     margin-left: 5px;
     font-size:16px;
    }
    #tweetit {
     color: #487B96 !important;
     font-size:16px;
     margin: 3px 0 -4px 0;
    }
    #photos {
     background-image: url(images/flickrheader.jpg);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     width: 665px;
     clear:both;
    }
    <div id="cityevents">
            <h2> Events </h2>

            <table>
            <th>Date </th><th> Who's Playing </th><th> Venue </th><th> City </th><th> Tickets </th>
            <tr><td>May 28</td><td><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/5384486?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'>Jill King</a></td><td>Open Eye Cafe</td><td>Carrboro</td><td style='text-align:center;'><span style='color: #999'> Find </span></td></tr><tr><td>May 28</td><td><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/5281141?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'>Ahleuchatistas</a></td><td>Nightlight</td><td>Chapel Hill</td><td style='text-align:center;'><span style='color: #999'> Find </span></td></tr><tr><td>May 28</td><td><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/4970896?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'>Sam Quinn</a></td><td>Local 506</td><td>Chapel Hill</td><td style='text-align:center;'><span style='color: #999'> Find </span></td></tr><tr><td>May 29</td><td><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/5303661?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'>Cagematch Mayhem, Champion Vs Au Jus, Heartbreaker Vs Au Jus</a></td><td>DSI Comedy Theater</td><td>Carrboro</td><td style='text-align:center;'><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/5303661/tickets?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'> Find </a></td></tr><tr><td>May 29</td><td><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/4722066?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'>Lewd Acts, Converge, Gaza, Black Breath</a></td><td>Cat's Cradle</td><td>Carrboro</td><td style='text-align:center;'><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/4722066/tickets?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'> Find </a></td></tr><tr><td>May 29</td><td><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/4647076?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'>Nate Currin</a></td><td>Broad Street Cafe</td><td>Durham</td><td style='text-align:center;'><span style='color: #999'> Find </span></td></tr><tr><td>May 29</td><td><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/5580211?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'>International Night</a></td><td>Serena Rtp</td><td>Durham</td><td style='text-align:center;'><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/5580211/tickets?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'> Find </a></td></tr><tr><td>May 29</td><td><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/4770241?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'>Jill King</a></td><td>Caffe Driade</td><td>Chapel Hill</td><td style='text-align:center;'><span style='color: #999'> Find </span></td></tr><tr><td>May 29</td><td><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/5406411?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'>Sunbears!</a></td><td>Local 506</td><td>Chapel Hill</td><td style='text-align:center;'><span style='color: #999'> Find </span></td></tr><tr><td>May 29</td><td><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/4924136?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'>Studio Gangsters</a></td><td>The Reservoir</td><td>Carrboro</td><td style='text-align:center;'><span style='color: #999'> Find </span></td></tr><tr><td>May 30</td><td><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/5252161?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'>She Wants Revenge</a></td><td>Cat's Cradle</td><td>Carrboro</td><td style='text-align:center;'><span style='color: #999'> Find </span></td></tr><tr><td>May 30</td><td><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/4436326?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'>Unheard Radio Battle of the Bands</a></td><td>Mansion 462</td><td>Chapel Hill</td><td style='text-align:center;'><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/4436326/tickets?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'> Find </a></td></tr><tr><td>May 30</td><td><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/4924141?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'>Studio Gangsters</a></td><td>The Cave</td><td>Chapel Hill</td><td style='text-align:center;'><span style='color: #999'> Find </span></td></tr><tr><td>Jun 2</td><td><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/5252881?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'>Jeanne Jolly</a></td><td>Caffe Driade</td><td>Chapel Hill</td><td style='text-align:center;'><span style='color: #999'> Find </span></td></tr><tr><td>Jun 2</td><td><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/4628026?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'>James Husband, Of Montreal</a></td><td>Cat's Cradle</td><td>Carrboro</td><td style='text-align:center;'><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/4628026/tickets?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'> Find </a></td></tr><tr><td>Jun 2</td><td><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/5019466?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'>Camera Obscura</a></td><td>Duke Gardens</td><td>Durham</td><td style='text-align:center;'><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/5019466/tickets?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'> Find </a></td></tr><tr><td>Jun 3</td><td><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/4226511?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'>Reverend Horton Heat, Cracker, Legendary Shack Shakers</a></td><td>Cat's Cradle</td><td>Carrboro</td><td style='text-align:center;'><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/4226511/tickets?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'> Find </a></td></tr><tr><td>Jun 3</td><td><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/5253371?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'>American Aquarium</a></td><td>Local 506</td><td>Chapel Hill</td><td style='text-align:center;'><span style='color: #999'> Find </span></td></tr><tr><td>Jun 4</td><td><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/4285251?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'>Laurence Juber</a></td><td>The ArtsCenter</td><td>Carrboro</td><td style='text-align:center;'><span style='color: #999'> Find </span></td></tr><tr><td>Jun 4</td><td><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/5642566?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'>Community Jam, Pt Scarborough Is a Movie, Armageddon'it</a></td><td>DSI Comedy Theater</td><td>Carrboro</td><td style='text-align:center;'><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/5642566/tickets?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'> Find </a></td></tr><tr><td>Jun 4</td><td><a href='http://www.songkick.com/concerts/4676216?utm_source=1121&utm_medium=partner' target='_blank'>Big Bill Morganfield</a></td><td>Papa Mojos Roadhouse</td><td>Durham</td><td style='text-align:center;'><span style='color: #999'> Find </span></td></tr>                 </table>

                </div> <!-- Events -->
                <div id="citywhatsup">
            <h2> What's Up? 
            <div id="tweetit"><a class="btn-slide">Tell em'</a>
            </div></h2>
            <div id="twitpanel"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">

     twttr.anywhere(function (T) {

    T("#twitpanel").tweetBox({
      height: 100,
      width: 215,
      label: '',
      defaultContent: ""
    });

     });

   </script> 
            <script type="text/javascript">

    twttr.anywhere(function (T) {
      T("#whatsup").linkifyUsers();
    });
            </script>

            <ul>
            <li><img src='http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/898693876/4604414396_0464180430_b_normal.jpg' alt='kaiten_keiku' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px; float: left; padding-right:4px;'/> @kaiten_keiku: <span style='text-align:justify;'>@Charlotte_Nao ありがとうでしゅ～さみしくなんかない！</span> - <span class='twittertime'>May 28 12:37AM</span></li><hr/><li><img src='http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/612153581/bowdown_normal.jpg' alt='bugn' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px; float: left; padding-right:4px;'/> @bugn: <span style='text-align:justify;'>@Bravotv (sitc2 as rhony) Bethenny-Carrie, Sonja-Samantha, Alex-Miranda, Ramona-Charlotte</span> - <span class='twittertime'>May 28 12:36AM</span></li><hr/><li><img src='http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/844630278/mj_normal.jpg' alt='Myra_Jones' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px; float: left; padding-right:4px;'/> @Myra_Jones: <span style='text-align:justify;'>@t_weet123 If you're still in Charlotte then you need to head to Whiskey River...they say Luke B. just walked in and started drinking.</span> - <span class='twittertime'>May 28 12:36AM</span></li><hr/><li><img src='http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/936667468/110971230_normal.jpg' alt='THEORACLE2' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px; float: left; padding-right:4px;'/> @THEORACLE2: <span style='text-align:justify;'>@MsKamilah08 are yall in charlotte?</span> - <span class='twittertime'>May 28 12:36AM</span></li><hr/><li><img src='http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/767244842/7AM_normal.jpg' alt='mtollefsrud' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px; float: left; padding-right:4px;'/> @mtollefsrud: <span style='text-align:justify;'>@vosler09 thinks I'm Charlotte.</span> - <span class='twittertime'>May 28 12:36AM</span></li><hr/><li><img src='http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/936496517/DSCF0317_-_Copy_normal.JPG' alt='Thasian' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px; float: left; padding-right:4px;'/> @Thasian: <span style='text-align:justify;'>I like #CharMeck #Charlotte  | Atlanta = #No #FAIL #EPICFAIL</span> - <span class='twittertime'>May 28 12:36AM</span></li><hr/><li><img src='http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/695551715/NASCAR_logo_flag_normal.jpg' alt='NascarNewsNow' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px; float: left; padding-right:4px;'/> @NascarNewsNow: <span style='text-align:justify;'>#NASCAR #RACING News from the track: Charlotte Motor Speedway | Nascar Leath: Ahh, the waiting is... http://bit.ly/b2DToq #NHRA #DAYTONA500</span> - <span class='twittertime'>May 28 12:35AM</span></li>            </ul>

            </div>
            <div id="photos">
            <h2> Recent Photos </h2>
                   <ul>
       <li><a href='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4029/4646832962_980f936db9.jpg' target='_blank' rel='lightbox-photos' title='05 23 10 Jamie's Baby Shower 097'><img src='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4029/4646832962_980f936db9_t.jpg' alt='05 23 10 Jamie's Baby Shower 097' height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3176/4646218481_d06829a778.jpg' target='_blank' rel='lightbox-photos' title='summer'><img src='http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3176/4646218481_d06829a778_t.jpg' alt='summer' height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4032/4646833312_7b1de5390a.jpg' target='_blank' rel='lightbox-photos' title='100_0064'><img src='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4032/4646833312_7b1de5390a_t.jpg' alt='100_0064' height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4008/4646832834_784a0a9ed1.jpg' target='_blank' rel='lightbox-photos' title=''><img src='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4008/4646832834_784a0a9ed1_t.jpg' alt='' height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4066/4646218735_b37d8fd9e5.jpg' target='_blank' rel='lightbox-photos' title='DSC05524'><img src='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4066/4646218735_b37d8fd9e5_t.jpg' alt='DSC05524' height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4054/4646830604_97afd54623.jpg' target='_blank' rel='lightbox-photos' title='DTLA graff'><img src='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4054/4646830604_97afd54623_t.jpg' alt='DTLA graff' height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4066/4646833048_7a9ab28733.jpg' target='_blank' rel='lightbox-photos' title='100_0243.jpg'><img src='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4066/4646833048_7a9ab28733_t.jpg' alt='100_0243.jpg' height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3399/4646832626_de89d0fb0e.jpg' target='_blank' rel='lightbox-photos' title='6W看到心跳'><img src='http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3399/4646832626_de89d0fb0e_t.jpg' alt='6W看到心跳' height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4005/4646832826_0d9e8afe19.jpg' target='_blank' rel='lightbox-photos' title='IMG_9381'><img src='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4005/4646832826_0d9e8afe19_t.jpg' alt='IMG_9381' height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4046/4646830752_dfc32b1740.jpg' target='_blank' rel='lightbox-photos' title='11'><img src='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4046/4646830752_dfc32b1740_t.jpg' alt='11' height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4010/4646215929_80b78f0007.jpg' target='_blank' rel='lightbox-photos' title='GEDC8592'><img src='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4010/4646215929_80b78f0007_t.jpg' alt='GEDC8592' height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4064/4646832384_7fc8d31e11.jpg' target='_blank' rel='lightbox-photos' title='2010 Advanced Grappling'><img src='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4064/4646832384_7fc8d31e11_t.jpg' alt='2010 Advanced Grappling' height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4049/4646218143_c108276325.jpg' target='_blank' rel='lightbox-photos' title='P1270352'><img src='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4049/4646218143_c108276325_t.jpg' alt='P1270352' height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4009/4646217767_3900f39475.jpg' target='_blank' rel='lightbox-photos' title='P1270351'><img src='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4009/4646217767_3900f39475_t.jpg' alt='P1270351' height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4027/4646831284_30b6e6da36.jpg' target='_blank' rel='lightbox-photos' title='Image245'><img src='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4027/4646831284_30b6e6da36_t.jpg' alt='Image245' height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3399/4646218295_63a899d322.jpg' target='_blank' rel='lightbox-photos' title='IMG_0037'><img src='http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3399/4646218295_63a899d322_t.jpg' alt='IMG_0037' height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4059/4646218159_01d5b02c3f.jpg' target='_blank' rel='lightbox-photos' title='DooDah2010-6665'><img src='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4059/4646218159_01d5b02c3f_t.jpg' alt='DooDah2010-6665' height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4053/4646834404_615e09b715.jpg' target='_blank' rel='lightbox-photos' title='IMG_2668'><img src='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4053/4646834404_615e09b715_t.jpg' alt='IMG_2668' height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li>             </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="videos">

            <h2> Recent Videos </h2>
             <ul>
    <li><a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_oc5-0yFoYg&feature=youtube_gdata' target='_blank'><img src='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/_oc5-0yFoYg/default.jpg'height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pRXKeYVYHc&feature=youtube_gdata' target='_blank'><img src='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/1pRXKeYVYHc/default.jpg'height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzRQUu-ZBdw&feature=youtube_gdata' target='_blank'><img src='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/yzRQUu-ZBdw/default.jpg'height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mud-A76nLro&feature=youtube_gdata' target='_blank'><img src='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/mud-A76nLro/default.jpg'height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TLOboW19_OA&feature=youtube_gdata' target='_blank'><img src='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/TLOboW19_OA/default.jpg'height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PcYja2jjvi0&feature=youtube_gdata' target='_blank'><img src='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/PcYja2jjvi0/default.jpg'height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKjklCEMrPk&feature=youtube_gdata' target='_blank'><img src='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/KKjklCEMrPk/default.jpg'height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AyUwY6PRX0Y&feature=youtube_gdata' target='_blank'><img src='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/AyUwY6PRX0Y/default.jpg'height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Sf2-7RjVYs&feature=youtube_gdata' target='_blank'><img src='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/8Sf2-7RjVYs/default.jpg'height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGMayoJmhE8&feature=youtube_gdata' target='_blank'><img src='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/xGMayoJmhE8/default.jpg'height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paseBeB6Cb8&feature=youtube_gdata' target='_blank'><img src='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/paseBeB6Cb8/default.jpg'height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_FSRUtMMik&feature=youtube_gdata' target='_blank'><img src='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/l_FSRUtMMik/default.jpg'height=100px; width=100px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li>                </ul>
            </div>
  </div><!-- #content -->
```

Comment: The last div in your code is identified by videos. Did you mean the photos div ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to change the right sidebar to float:right instead of float:left.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you have clear:both; in #photos. Clear will create a top margin to clear floated elements.